# How to differentiate Object and Field When both api names are same

Tags: api

How to differentiate object and field having same api name
ex:   object api name Cold_Fever__c and field api name is also Cold_Fever__c

Comment: try to use describe call to check it is sobject type or a field type

Answer (score 1):

why do you need this? You always should now what are you using or provide more description of your task.

Here it is an example:

ApexClass

```
@isTest
private class SobjectType {


    @isTest static void test_method_one() {

        List<Cold_Fever__c> cfs = [SELECT Id, Cold_Fever__c FROM Cold_Fever__c];
        System.assertEquals(0, cfs.size());

        Schema.SObjectType S = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Cold_Fever__c');
        System.debug(S);

        Map<String,Schema.SObjectField> fieldsMap = S.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
        Schema.SObjectField F = fieldsMap.get(Cold_Fever__c.Cold_Fever__c.getDescribe().getName());
        Schema.DescribeFieldResult R = F.getDescribe();

        System.debug(R.getName());
        System.debug(R.getLabel());
    }

}
```